# How can I beautify the below java query using java stream filter and predicate?

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

How can I beautify the below java query using java stream filter and predicate?

I have this piece of code where its trying to throw some exceptions based on some condition which needs to be handled at UI level. How can I shorten the below code into more precise using java stream filter and predicate.

```
public Sort resolveArgument() {

    Sort sort = sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument();

    List<Sort.Order> orders = sort.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (orders.isEmpty()) {
        sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, default_sort_param);
    } else {
        if (orders.size() > sort_max_count) {
            throw new InvalidSortException("Please provide only 3 valid sort parameters.");
        }
    }

    orders.forEach(order -> {
        if (!allowed_sort_params.contains(order.getProperty())) {
            throw new InvalidSortException(order.getProperty() + " is not a valid sort parameter");
        }
    });

    return sort;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `forEach` call can be replaced with:

```
orders.stream().map(Sort.Order::getProperty).filter(x -> !allowed_sort_params.contains(x))
    .findFirst().ifPresent(x -> {
        throw new InvalidSortException(x + " is not a valid sort parameter");
    });
```

However, IMO this is not much of an improvement.

Comment: order.getProperty() is throwing compile time exception.

Comment: @SharmisthaChakraborty Ah, so you are using `order` in the `throw` statement. See the edit.

Comment: Hello @Sweeper : Instead of finding first instance of invalid sort param and throwing exception, can we handle it in functional way like collect all invalid sort params, prepare message with all them listed and finally throw InvalidSortParam exception?

Comment: @SharmisthaChakraborty Yes, but you did not mention that in your question. Your question just says "beautify using java stream filter and predicate", which means to keep the same behaviour, but rewrite the code using different APIs. Please ask another question for that.

Comment: Thanks. I just did...Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061481/how-can-we-handle-the-below-code-in-functional-way